# STEP 2013 P1 Statistics and Probability Question

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics, solution-verification

The aim to the following: From a deck of 52 cards (numbered from 1,2,3,...,52) I pick 7 cards, each card having the same probability of being picked. What is the probability that only two of the selected cards add up to 53?

My approach:

Say we have the cards $A,B,C,D,E,F \text{ and } G$. The probability that a randomly selected card, say $A$, from these $7$ has its *pair* in the set is $\frac{6}{51}$. Say this pair is $B$. Now we need to figure out the number of other possible pairs and the probability that a given number doesn't have its pair. The probability that a number doesn't have its pair (from the $5$ numbers left) is $1-\frac{5}{51}=\frac{46}{51}$. There are $\binom{5}{2}=10$ many different possible pairs. Thus the probability that exactly one pair add up to $53$ is

$$p=\frac{6}{51}(\frac{46}{51})^{10}.$$

According to the markscheme this is wrong. Could somebody let me know why is that?

Comment: Why is it true that "the probability that a randomly selected card, say A, from these 7 has its pair in the set is $\frac{6}{51}$"?

Comment: My logic was that selecting 1 card, the probability that another card complements it (so that they add up to 53) is $\frac{1}{52-1}$. There are 6 such possible cards so I get $\frac{6}{51}$. Is this wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a natural pairing of the cards into $26$ pairs that sum to $53$: $1-52,2-51$ and so on. Indeed, these are the only ways to make $53$ from two cards in the set.

The number of hands with only two cards – one pair – summing to $53$ is the product of

- $26$ ways to select the pair in hand
- $\binom{25}5$ ways to select the pairs the other five picked cards reside in – each of these cards must reside in its own pair
- $2^5=32$ ways to select which card in the selected single-card pairs is actually in the hand

Thus the final probability is
$$\frac{26×\binom{25}5×32}{\binom{52}7}$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I understand your solution, however, I do not understand why is what I have written wrong. Could you please assist me with that?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. I gave these letters for clarity, I thought it would have been easier than saying suppose that two cards form a pair what is the probability of that occurring and then what is the probability that the remaining cards do not form any pairs. Could you elaborate why I would have to multiply by 21 specifically?

Comment: thank you for the comment. I see what you mean. My issue with statistics tends to be that I do not go for the right approach because I do not understand what is wrong with my current one (or don't really understand how the restrictions apply). Do you have any suggestions as in how to better approach statistics problems? Maybe to always try using combinatorials rather than direct probabilities?

Comment: @MathsWizzard The problem here is a _discrete_ problem, where the object of study takes any one of a _finite_ number of forms. For such problems, combinatorics is the way to go.

Comment: thank you very much for this advice, I will add this to my notes. Excuse my incompetence in statistics. I am really trying to spend time on it so that it is as good as the areas I specialize in.

Comment: @MathsWizzard Now, please accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

There are $52\cdot51\cdot50\cdots46$ ways to choose $7$ cards. There are $\binom72=21$ ways to choose which two cards will be paired, $26$ ways to choose the pair, and $2$ ways to distribute the pair to the chosen positions.

The first of the remaining $5$ cards can be chosen in $50$ ways, the next in $48$ ways, and so on, because once we choose a card we cannot choose it or its pair.  This gives a probability of $$\frac{21\cdot52\cdot50\cdot48\cdot46\cdot44\cdot42}{52\cdot51\cdot50\cdot49\cdot48\cdot47\cdot46}$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I understand your solution, however, I do not understand why is what I have written wrong. Could you please assist me with that?